# Scoring Game Does Not Execute Properly

Tags: java

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Some data might also be helpful. All strikes is 300.

I have deleted my information as per my teacher's request. I tried deleting the post but Stack Overflow would not let me. Sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: For starters, I don't see any data structure anywhere for "frames" ;)  Among other things, each "frame" should keep track of which "pins" were knocked down for each of the two (or three!) "throws".

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION (per above): please refactor your code, to leverage "classes".  You should have as *little* code as possible in "main()".  Certainly no "business logic" outside of a class.  But your immediate problem is elsewhere.  Look here for how to score: https://www.bowlinggenius.com/.  Note that a "perfect game" will have scores {30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300}

Comment: Q: Any luck?  Was the bowlingjenius.com link helpful in figuring out your arithmetic error?  We realize it's asking alot of a beginner ... but any interest in refactoring your code into at least one additional class (even just a "game", where you "throw" from main ... but the class has all the "logic")?, And/or experimenting with "unit tests"?  Please do keep us posted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is no question anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a pro tip, which might be hard to use at first, but will save you lots of time.

Write unit tests! This will force you to model it better.

First, pretend you don't care about user input. Create a java class called Game. Add a method called init() that sets up the game. Add another method shot(int pins) that allows you to knock down some pins. Add another method getScore() that returns the score.

Now you can write a test. The test should init the game, take shot, and check the score. If the score is wrong it should throw an error.

Then add another test, perhaps to check scoring on a spare.

Slowly build this out until you have tested all your cases. Perhaps you will need a method that returns what frame you are playing? Lastly, add user input. Whenever the user takes a turn, report the frame and score.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I agree.  And to repeat myself: writing a "unit test" presupposes that you've encapsulated your "business logic" into  *classes* with *behavior* that you can test.

Answer (score 0):

You're logic is spread out quite poorly. In one if statement you print out that they got a strike, and then a few statements down you check to see if it is a strike.

You should combine these statements where applicable.

For instance:

```
        if (pinsDown1 == 10) {
            isStrike = true;
        }

 if(isStrike) {
            score += pinsDown1;
            score += pinsDown2;
            if(isStrike && pinsDown1 == 10) {
                isTwoStrikes = true;
            }
            isStrike = false;
            System.out.println("The score is: " + score);
        }
```

Could be a single if statement. You should revise your code because there are more instances of this case and it makes it very difficult to read and understand. Also you don't make use of functions whatsoever, they might also help in reducing the amount of times you repeat yourself throughout your code.

Comment: I agree "the logic is spread out quite poorly".  To fix this, the OP should refactor the code into "classes".  For example, a "Game" object, consisting of 10 "frames" objects.